# MySQL Error trying to use PayPal's API

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I am trying to get a script running and the checkout process (through PayPal) is killing me.

I am getting the following error:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /html/affiliate/classes/XpDb.php on line 22
>   Could not connect: Could not connect:

On my PayPal account, I see the transactions taking place.
But on my website, I just end up seeing the error above.

I am very new to this and any help getting me going in the right direction would

Comment: is your database config file setup right?

Comment: It appears to be. The pages all work ok. records are updated fine, just the checkout process is the only hangup.

Comment: tracked down the config file. That was the problem after all. But now its telling me that the number of items in the cart didnt match the number of total items. You didnt run into any of these problems?

Comment: na, try refreshing the order, i looked up the md5 for e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e and its 123456 so all users that sign up with the fb connect have that pass...classic

Comment: top notch, this thing is killin me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i installed that groupon clone for a client today, that script has so many problems its badly written, i had to fix the facebook login, paypal api, and some of the jquery on the backend. it may look nice but thats about it..

Comment: i agree, im fighting an uphill battle with this thing. Did you run into DB problems?

Comment: What did you have to do to the PayPal API?

Comment: it installed fine, but when i had to trace through the code to fix&change stuff i saw variables that weren't used and functions that returned static content all over the place, i also noticed that all the facebook users are given the same md5 password.

Comment: on the ipn success, javascript just redirects with window.location = '/view_coopon/'; which dont exist, i removed it and made a query that updated the db then directed them back to there profile that already has a link to there coupons.

Comment: Yea I have seen some real shotty work on this thing, I noticed in one of their functions that they cc'ed themselves on the registration emails sent out to new users of the site.

Comment: no offense but these scripts are quickly released no care in the code and not fully tested to take advantage of the groupon hype. and they charge like $399 USD for some. easy money lol